# How to calculate the new sequence number N for the new final field Fp curve?

Tags: secp256k1, math

Are there simplified algorithms or online services or Python scripts where can calculate a new ordinal `N` for a new finite field `Fp` in an elliptic curve?

```
y^2 = x^3 + 7
```

I know that SageMath exists and in this program can make a calculation using the `EllipticCurve ()` function, but I'm more interested in Python.

Comment: You want Schoof's algorithm for this, which is pretty nontrivial. A web search for "Python Schoof" finds this: https://github.com/pdinges/python-schoof. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Pieter Wuille Yes, that's what I need! Thank you!